# How to create this rounded object?

Tags: smartobject

How to create the rounded object behind the circles in Adobe Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: http://shspage.com/aijs/en#metaball Download link for the whole script package is at the top.

Comment: I'm going to have a play with this, thank you!

Comment: Hi Diederik, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 7):

SURELY there is a better way to do this, and I'm going to follow this to see what people suggest. But, this is 9/10, what I would do:

[image: Circle Demo]
[image: Circle Demo 2]

Basically, I would create a shape with the pen tool as I've done in step 2 and then mirror it like I've done in step 3. There's nothing too mathematically pleasing about this solution (I feel like there's probably a sounder solution with the pathfinder tool) but it works.

Comment: Well demonstrated answer.